# How to fix permission requests not being sent on iOS in an expo project

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm currently in the middle of an expo app development course and am currently on the part where you have to ask for permissions to use the camera. Whenever I load up the app, however, it does not ask me in a pop up for permission and has no errors. It is supposed to pop up and say something along the lines of "So and so wants to access your camera." Using the expo documentation and the video, I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I'm currently on Expo 33.0, React Native 0.59.9, and am running the app on my iPhone XR, iOS 12.1.4. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import {Camera} from "expo-camera";
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import {FontAwesome} from "@expo/vector-icons";

export default class CameraScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            hasCameraPermission: null,
            type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
            isFlashLightOn: Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off,
        }
    }

    static navigationOption = {
        title: "Camera"
    }

    //ask for permission
    async componentDidMount() {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
      this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
    }

    render(){
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Camera Screen</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are running the project on the Expo app and you already granted access to the camera before you probably don't need to grant access again. You can un-grant access to the camera by going to **Settings > Expo** and switch off the camera.

Comment: @CarlosAbraham That was exactly what was wrong, such a simple thing but so easy to overlook. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the project on the Expo app and you already granted access to the camera before you probably don't need to grant access again. You can un-grant access to the camera by going to **Settings > Expo** and switch off the camera.

[image]

Comment: Thanks once again!